# Timeout locking table after upgrade to 1.4.195

Tags: h2

Recently i have upgraded my H2 database from 1.3.178 to 1.4.195. When i try to alter a table with few records (less than 5.000) i get this error:

```
Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE foo ADD bar VARCHAR [50200-195] HYT00/50200 (Aiuto)
```

The error does not appear with the older version 1.3.178.

I tried to set a bigger timeout using `LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000` but it had no effect. Instead, i solved the problem using the parameter `LOCK_MODE=3`.

According to [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation) the parameter `LOCK_MODE=3` is the default, so why i need to specify it?

Comment: I had a similar issue with h2 v1.4.187. Setting `LOCK_MODE=0` did the trick. At least your question led me to a working solution (even though I'm not sure yet what's happening...)